# How to use user properties of FirebaseAnalytics on flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics

I'm using the 'setUserProperty()' function on my registration button and I want to use the property in another screen, how can I do that?

```
final FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
await analytics.setUserProperty(name: 'name', value: 'TEXT');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind [setting a user property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/user-properties) with Firebase Analytics is for you to tag users with data in order to make it easy for you filter users in the analytics dashboard, and other analytics-related functions.  It's not meant for you to get those properties later.  If you want to associate some data per user, you should consider using a database or some other read/write storage.